# jQuery AJAX error handling How to separate returned error messages into individual li's

Tags: jquery

Working with some data returned from a database. All data is returned in a table, in one td specifically. The mark up of the returned data is as such

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>Field Name</td>
        <td>Field Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SuccessFlag</td>
        <td>False</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ResponseMessage</td>
        <td>Invalid email address, Invalid User Name, etc., etc</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

in my error handling, I'm able to get to the 6th td and show the error no problem.

```
success: function(data) {
    var answer = $(data).find("td:eq(3)").text();
    var message = $(data).find("td:eq(5)").text();
    if (answer==="True") {
        $("#bottomContent").load("page.php #div");
        } else {
        $('#processing').hide();
        $('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]').val("");
        $('#messageBox').show().html('<ul><li>' + message + '</li></ul>');
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, it would output all of the contents in one li. I would like to figure out how to split them at the ',' and create an individual li for each item after the split.

Answer (score 2):

I know this solution is not using jQuery, but have you considered using knockoutjs. It simplifies client side data binding significantly.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: errorMessages ">
    <li>
        <label data-bind="text: title"></label>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
// Use knockout observable array
var errorMessages = ko.observableArray();

success: function(data) {
var answer = $(data).find("td:eq(3)").text();
var message = $(data).find("td:eq(5)").text();
if (answer==="True") {
    $("#bottomContent").load("page.php #div");
    } else {
    $('#processing').hide();
    $('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]').val("");

    // Knockout array will automatically bind to your DOM
    this.errorMessages(message);
    }
}
</script>
```

You may need to man-handle your 'message' variable into a JSON collection instead of a table.